# Is there an issue with using a generic page wrapping component with react-router-dom v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router-dom v6 in a React app. I have routes with url params. When the params change, the element prop of the route (which is a component) rerenders, but the useEffect that has the params as dependencies does not trigger before the data in my component becomes inconsistent, causing the app to crash (white screen). My solution is to wrap all my Route element props with component that passes the params as the key to the Component I want to render. It works just fine, but I feel like I shouldn't be doing this. That either there is a more proper solution, or that I will encounter issues later on that I am not anticipating. I appreciate any advice on the matter. Thank you

Here is my Wrapper component:

```
const PageWrapper = ({page}) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const key = JSON.stringify(params);
  return <div key={key}>{page}</div>
}
```

And this is how all my routes look:

```
<Route
    path={`thing_type/:thing_type_id`}
    element={
        <PageWrapper
            page={<ThingTypePage/>}
            />
    }
/>
```

It is a bit ugly and cluttered to have all my routes look like this, but it is all contained in the file with my routes, so I can deal with it. (I have the routes as 1-liners, but spread it out her for readability)

I have tried passing the params as the key directly to the element prop, but it is not supported in react-router-dom v6.

Edit:
The issue only arrises when I navigate to the same page twice, but with different params. If another page is navigated to between that, there is no issue. The inconsistency in data that causes the crash comes from mixing of data that is cached client side in the React app with data fetched from the server. This is a boiled down example of my Page:

```
const ThingTypePage = () => {
    const {thing_type_id} = useParams();
    const {cachedStaticData} = React.useContext(Context);

    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        setData(null);
        const body = {thing_type_id};
        const onSucceeded = (response) => setData(response.data);
        const onFailed = (err) => setData(false);
        myFetch("myBackendUrlExtension", body, onSucceeded, onFailed);
    }, [thing_type_id])

    if(data === null) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    if(data === false) return <div>Failed to load</div>;
    
    const things = data.instances;
    const thingTypeObjectStructure = getThingTypeObjectStructure(cachedStaticData, thing_type_id);
    // at this point things = data from previous fetch, when thing_type_id = old_id
    // but thingTypeObjectStructure has the updated value, using thing_type_id = new_id
    
    return (
        <div key={`ThingTypePage-${thing_type_id}`}>
            <ThingsTable
                // here 'things' is being rendered with a false assumption of their object structure
                // causing crashes (accessing undefined)
                things = {things}
                structure = {thingTypeObjectStructure}
                />
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd say this is an anti-pattern and that you've some logical issue going on in your routed components if you need to do this for a majority of your routes. I don't think you should have much need to do this at all, really. Can you [edit] to provide details on the ***actual*** issue or problem you are having and include a more complete [mcve]? In effect it seems you are asking an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you, I edited the question. Hope it is better now.

Comment: When `myFetch` completes successfully and updates the `data` state, I don't think it's correct/possible for `data` to still be the old value from any previous render, `ThingTypePage` would have rerendered and the new version of `data` closed over in scope. Is the value returned by `onSucceeded` the updated value you expect? Does `getThingTypeObjectStructure` correctly return a current computed `thingTypeObjectStructure` based on current state/props?

Comment: @DrewReese , so the issue is that the `useEffect` does not even refire yet, so the new data is not fetched. to answer your questions explicitly: yes, the data value set in `onSucceded` is correct when it runs, but it is not being set at all due to the effect not running. And yes, `getThingTypeObjectStructure` returns the correct value. It works for all values of `thing_type_id`, but can crash for any value of `thing_type_id`, it is just a matter of if the page is rendered twice consecutively with different values for `thing_type_id`.

Comment: Ah, I see. `ThingTypePage` rerenders because the `thing_type_id` path parameter changes, this triggers the effect to run, it enqueues `setData(null);` which *will* trigger a `ThingTypePage` component rerender... and it's this current render cycle where `data` is still the current data but the `thing_type_id` is the next value. So basically is the issue that `thing_type_id` (*and `data`*) and `thingTypeObjectStructure` are "out-of-sync" when passed to the `ThingsTable` component?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what was happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this is a bit of an anti-pattern and that you've some logical issue going on in your routed components if you need to do this for a majority of your routes. I don't think you should have much need to do this at all, really.

It would appear here that ***both*** `data` ***and*** `thingTypeObjectStructure` have a dependency on the `thing_type_id` path parameter value, and it becomes an issue when the fetched `data` state and computed/derived `thingTypeObjectStructure` get out of sync because of the way React component state updates work with the render cycle.

My suggestion here would be to convert `thingTypeObjectStructure` also to a React state such that it can by computed and updated ***at the same time*** as the `data` state.

Example:

```
const ThingTypePage = () => {
  const { thing_type_id } = useParams();
  const { cachedStaticData } = React.useContext(Context);

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(null);

    const body = { thing_type_id };
    const onSucceeded = ({ data }) => {
      setData({
        things: data.instances,
        structure: getThingTypeObjectStructure(
          cachedStaticData,
          thing_type_id
        ),
      });
    };
    const onFailed = () => setData(false);

    myFetch("myBackendUrlExtension", body, onSucceeded, onFailed);
  }, [cachedStaticData , thing_type_id]);

  if (data === null) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  if (data === false) return <div>Failed to load</div>;
    
  const { things, structure } = data;
    
  return (
    <div>
      <ThingsTable
        things={things}
        structure={structure}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You should now be able to remove the wrapper component from the routed content.

```
<Route
  path="thing_type/:thing_type_id"
  element={<ThingTypePage />}
/>
```